# Regex python parse files

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#fixed the import, just red PEP 8
import re 
###################################################
def extract(data):
    ms = re.match(r'(\S+).*mid:(\d+)' , data) # heure & mid 
    k = re.findall(r"/(\S+)", data) # source & destination  
    exp = result = re.findall(r'NVS:([\w\.]+)',data) # type S & D
    # if the table length is 1 it means that the origin is unknown
    if len(k)==1:
      return {'Heure':ms.group(1), 'mid':ms.group(2),"Origine":"Unknown","Destination":k[0],"Type S":exp[0],"Type D":exp[1]}
    # if the table length it means that there's a a source and a destination
    if len(k)==2:
      return {'Heure':ms.group(1), 'mid':ms.group(2),"Origine":k[0],"Destination":k[1],"Type S":exp[0],"Type D":exp[1]}
```

---

well the issue is that when i have lines like that where there's `[NVS:FAXG3.1.0/+44614215421]` it returns None, is there way to make is stop at the second `NVS:` so that it stopps like if we have a line like `data2`

```
data = "13:16:16.146 mta         Messages       I CC Doc O:NVS:SMTP/me@test.no R:NVS:SMTP.0/server@test.de [NVS:FAXG3.1.0/+44614215421] mid:41414"
print extract(data)
```

It returns

```
>>>None
```

---

```
data2 = "13:16:16.146 mta         Messages       I CC Doc O:NVS:SMTP/me@test.no R:NVS:SMTP.0/server@test.de  mid:41414"
print extract(data2)
```

It returns

---

```
>>> {'Destination': 'server@test.de', 'mid': '41414', 'Type S': 'SMTP', 'Origine': 'me@test.no', 'Type D': 'SMTP.0', 'Heure': '13:16:16.146'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Dirty hack*

Just replace

```
if len(k)==2:
```

to

```
if len(k)>1:
```

because it found more than 2 matches in the second string